# ng-grid: vertical bar not as high as it should be

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-grid

On my website, ng-grid looks like this:

[image: my ng-grid]

I've found out that this disappears, when I manually do:

```
.ngVerticalBar {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

I have commented out all irrelevant stylesheets of course. So there's only a reference to the ng-grid.css and my main.scss, but I'm not touching line-height over there.

Inspection reveals, that the compilation from scss to css introduces line-height: 1.428571429 on the body tag. Commenting this out and inspecting again reveals, that line-height isn't set anymore for that element, but height is set to 16px, although you don't see where it's coming from.
Since there's a

```
ng-style="{height: col.rowHeight}"
```

placed onto that div I'd guess that it's getting it from there.

So I took batarang and looked wether there is a rowHeight set on the col-object, but there's not.

So I guess I'm pretty stuck here...

**EDIT:** gridOptions.rowHeight is already set to 30.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing... What is really funny is that if I edit the "rowTemplate" in "ng-grid.debug.js" and add `{{rowHeight}}` before the `<ng-cell>` tag it shows the number on screen as "30" even though chrome shows that a height of 20 is coming from `ng-style:{height: rowHeight}`

Comment: I am experiencing this same thing too but it was everything okay until I started using Grunt (concat) so that gives me a hint that this could be related with the order of things? order of css and/or order of scripts

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying a fixed height in the CSS file, a more universal solution would be to use a percentage value.

```
<style>
    .ngVerticalBar {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set:

```
rowHeight:30
```

in `$scope.gridOptions`.

It's explained in the otions part [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/)

You can also set a particular rowHeight for Header and Footer.

You could also use a row template like in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPy8TLLEM1uJHEHK45hD?p=preview) where i force rowHeight to 80px and ngVerticalBar to 100%.

Compare the template to the original rowTemplate example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPy8TLLEM1uJHEHK45hD?p=preview)

Comment: The strange thing is, that gridOptions.rowHeight is already set to 30. Also I'm not using any row- or cell-template.

Comment: Also using a grid-template only works for rows within the grid. The header rows then are still seperated by half-assed-vertical-bars...

Answer (score 0):

Based the observation I made in the comment above, I came up with a work around using the literal value for ng-style in the template, like: `ng-style:{height: {{rowHeight}}px}`

Here are the two templates I have updated (putting this in code that runs AFTER "ng-grid.min.js":

```
angular.module("ngGrid").run(["$templateCache",
function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("headerRowTemplate.html",
      "<div ng-style=\"{ height: col.headerRowHeight }\" ng-repeat=\"col in renderedColumns\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\" class=\"ngHeaderCell\">" +
      " <div class=\"ngVerticalBar\" ng-style=\"{height: '{{col.headerRowHeight}}px'}\" ng-class=\"{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }\">&nbsp;</div>" +
      " <div ng-header-cell></div>" +
      "</div>"
  );


  $templateCache.put("rowTemplate.html",
      "<div ng-style=\"{ 'cursor': row.cursor }\" ng-repeat=\"col in renderedColumns\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\" class=\"ngCell {{col.cellClass}}\">" +
      " <div class=\"ngVerticalBar\" ng-style=\"{height: '{{rowHeight}}px'}\" ng-class=\"{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }\">&nbsp;</div>" +
      " <div ng-cell></div>" +
      "</div>"
  );
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround I was able to just add this override to my css:

```
.ngVerticalBar 
{
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

This of course assumes you have set 25 to be your rowHeight & headerRowHeight in gridOptions:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: yourData, 
  rowHeight: 25,
  headerRowHeight: 25}
```

It works but it means another page in the same app can't have a different row height without some more <strike>hacking</strike> work.